# Seaborn KDE visualisation, value error on dataset

Tags: python-2.7, seaborn

I am attempting to visualise a KDE plot in Seaborn, but am encountering an error on entering data.
The data is a set of scores ranging from 1-13 and is in the form of a numpy array.

Below is the section of code I'm using.

```
query_CNM = 'SELECT SCORE from CNMATCH LIMIT 2000'

df = pd.read_sql(query_CNM, conn, index_col = None)

yy = np.array(df)

plot = sns.kdeplot(yy)
```

Below is the full error that I'm receiving.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1758, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1147, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/uni/Desktop/Proof_Of_Concept/PYQTKDE.py", line 66, in <module>
    plot = sns.kdeplot(yy)
  File "/Users/uni/.conda/envs/fing.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 664, in kdeplot
    x, y = data.T
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I can't seem to find exactly how the data needs to be formatted for sea-born in order to fit a KDE, if any insights can be provided on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about if you try `df = pd.read_sql(query_CNM, conn, index_col = None').T`. Does it work?

Comment: Thank you, I get a new error: "ValueError: The number of observations must be larger than the number of variables."

Comment: Could you edit your answer with what does df look like? Why are you making an array and not passing it directly?

Comment: what is the shape of your `df`, of `yy` ?